# XSD validation issue with pattern when containing carriage return (&#13)

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns, xsd-validation, carriage-return

I have to check the validity of URLs in a large XML file.

I have to use this pattern to check if the URLs are valid or not:

```
<xs:simpleType name="url">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value="https?://([^/:]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}|([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(:[0-9]+)?((/|\?).*)?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Here's the java code to check the XML file against the XSD file (I use the library javax.xml.*):

```
Validator validator = xmlSchema.newValidator();
        
SAXSource sourceXML = new SAXSource(
        new NamespaceFilter(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()),
        new InputSource(new FileInputStream(new File(pathXmlFile)))
    );
        
validator.validate(sourceXML, null);
```

(note : NamespaceFilter is just a class extending XMLFilterImpl to avoid to check the namespace of the XML file)

Unfortunately, in the XML file, there are some URLs with the character "&#13;" which represents a carriage return:
[http://xxx.yyy.zz/exampleofurl\](http://xxx.yyy.zz/exampleofurl%5C)
containinganannoyingcarriagereturn

When I run my code with a XML file containing this kind of URL, I get this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 238719; columnNumber: 129; cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'http://xxx.yyy.zz/exampleofurl
containinganannoyingcarriagereturn' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern 'https?://([^/:]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}|([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(:[0-9]+)?((/|\?).*)?' for type 'url'.
```

It seems like the XSD validator interprets the "&#13;" as a carriage return and cause this issue when applying the pattern.

Is there a way to force the validator to not interpret this ASCII code?

From my point of view, the URL is valid and respect the pattern.

Comment: I don't understand. The string contains a character that the pattern doesn't allow. What makes you think it's valid?

Comment: Well, this example https://regex101.com/r/j9Wkmm/4 makes me think it should be valid. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tested the regex with a string containing the five character sequence `& # 1 3 ;`, which is accepted, because each of those five characters is matched by the meta-character ".".

But in XML, the five character sequence `& # 1 3 ;` represents a single character, codepoint 13. This is one of the two characters that the meta-character "." doesn't match (the other is codepoint 10).

You ask "Is there a way to force the validator to not interpret this ASCII code?" and the answer is no. XSD validation always operates on parsed XML, and XML parsing expands the entity reference.